# Max Value in DropDownList - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, max

How can I get the max value of a `DropDownList` values in `ASP.NET` with `C#`?

Is there any method or I should get it manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int maxValue = DropDownList1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Select(item => int.Parse(item.Value)).Max();`

Answer (score 1):

```
DropDownList1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Max(j => j.Value) // For string comparison
```

Or,

```
DropDownList1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Max(j => int.Parse(j.Value)) // If you want max int
```